# Toggling category markers with google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have multiple categories for the markers I show in my google map. The markers I have come from this dummydata I'm using for now:

```
var locations = [{
                    "Locatie":    "Den Bosch", 
                    "Latitude":   "51.700651", 
                    "Longitude":  "5.309143",
                    "Categorie":  "1"
                    },
                    {
                    "Locatie":    "Tilburg", 
                    "Latitude":   "51.555728", 
                    "Longitude":  "5.063324",
                    "Categorie":  "2"
                    },
                    {
                    "Locatie":    "Breda", 
                    "Latitude":   "51.582190", 
                    "Longitude":  "4.772186",
                    "Categorie":  "2"
                    },
                    {
                    "Locatie":    "Amsterdam", 
                    "Latitude":   "52.361345", 
                    "Longitude":  "4.887543",
                    "Categorie":  "1"
                    },
                    {
                    "Locatie":    "Utrecht", 
                    "Latitude":   "52.076974", 
                    "Longitude":  "5.103149",
                    "Categorie":  "1"
                    },
                    {
                    "Locatie":    "Heerenveen", 
                    "Latitude":   "52.956084", 
                    "Longitude":  "5.918884",
                    "Categorie":  "2"
                    },
                    {
                    "Locatie":    "Willekeurige Locatie", 
                    "Latitude":   "57.956084", 
                    "Longitude":  "8.918884",
                    "Categorie":  "2"
                    }];
```

As you can see I kept it simple and just made two categories, 1 or 2. The markers are placed on the map with this piece of code:

```
markers = [];

   var i, newMarker;

   for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
     newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].Latitude, locations[i].Longitude),
       map: map,
       title: locations[i].Locatie
     });

     newMarker.category = locations[i].Categorie;
     newMarker.setVisible(true);

     markers.push(newMarker);

     google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', (function(newMarker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i].Locatie);
          infowindow.open(map, newMarker);
        }
      })(newMarker, i));
   }
```

This step also works fine. Notice that when Google Maps loads I display all the markers regardless of the category they're in. Now what I want the user to be able to do is toggle markers from categories on and off, I have a function that fires when a toggle button is clicked:

```
function displayMarkers(category) {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].category === category) {
      markers[i].setVisible(true);
    }
    else {
      markers[i].setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}
```

What this does now is only show the markers that belong to the clicked category while it should toggle them on or off depending on if they were allready visible or not. I suppose i'd have to check if a category of markers is allready visible on the map or not and then based on that decide if I have to set `setVisible` to `true` or `false` for that specific group. I do not know how to achieve this with google maps. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I added some other pieces of my code that might be relevant to the question.

jQuery that handles the buttons:

```
jQuery('.cat-toggle').click(
     function () {
       var category = jQuery(this).attr("title");
       displayMarkers(category);
       jQuery(this).toggleClass("selected");
     }
);
```

The HTML for the buttons:

```
<a class="cat-toggle" title="1">category 1</a>
<a class="cat-toggle" title="2">category 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I deviate a little from your code.
But how about this?

- When creating the markers, you add an extra field 'visible' to var locations, and set it default to true 
  locations[i].visible = true;

Also, in the markup I prefer to keep data in the data- attribute, so example:

```
<a class="cat-toggle" data-cat="1">category 1</a>
```

You read this value like this:

```
var cat = $(this).data('cat');
```

- Then my click event becomes this: look in the code, at  $('.cat-toggle').click

---

Here is some code you can copy/paste as is.
( The info window doesn't work in this code; you have the extra code... )
But the toggle works.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,visualization,drawing,places&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var locations = [{
  "Locatie":    "Den Bosch", 
  "Latitude":   "51.700651", 
  "Longitude":  "5.309143",
  "Categorie":  "1"
  },
  {
  "Locatie":    "Tilburg", 
  "Latitude":   "51.555728", 
  "Longitude":  "5.063324",
  "Categorie":  "2"
  },
  {
  "Locatie":    "Breda", 
  "Latitude":   "51.582190", 
  "Longitude":  "4.772186",
  "Categorie":  "2"
  },
  {
  "Locatie":    "Amsterdam", 
  "Latitude":   "52.361345", 
  "Longitude":  "4.887543",
  "Categorie":  "1"
  },
  {
  "Locatie":    "Utrecht", 
  "Latitude":   "52.076974", 
  "Longitude":  "5.103149",
  "Categorie":  "1"
  },
  {
  "Locatie":    "Heerenveen", 
  "Latitude":   "52.956084", 
  "Longitude":  "5.918884",
  "Categorie":  "2"
  },
  {
  "Locatie":    "Willekeurige Locatie", 
  "Latitude":   "57.956084", 
  "Longitude":  "8.918884",
  "Categorie":  "2"
}];
</script>
<script>
var markers;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.cat-toggle').click(function() {
    var cat = $(this).data('cat');  // reads data-cat="..."
    // toggle
    for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
      if (locations[i].Categorie == cat) {    // goup by Categorie
        if (locations[i].visible == true) {   // Visible?  turn off
          locations[i].visible = false;
          markers[i].setVisible(false);
        }
        else {                                // invisible?  turn on
          locations[i].visible = true;
          markers[i].setVisible(true);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  initialize();
});

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52, 5.5),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  markers = [];
  var i, newMarker;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].Latitude, locations[i].Longitude),
      map: map,
      title: locations[i].Locatie
    });
    // we add a 'visible' flag to the locations data
    locations[i].visible = true;
    newMarker.setVisible(true);
    markers.push(newMarker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', (function(newMarker, i) {
       return function() {
         infowindow.setContent(locations[i].Locatie);
         infowindow.open(map, newMarker);
       }
     })(newMarker, i)
    );
  }
}
</script>
<style>
#map-canvas {
  height:400px;
}
.cat-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<a class="cat-toggle" data-cat="1">category 1</a>
<a class="cat-toggle" data-cat="2">category 2</a>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Groeten uit Brussel